# Update a MySQL row in one table depending upon a value in another table

Tags: mysql, transactions

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @v:=Clientno FROM A WHERE Case_No = '2000'; 
IF @V = ' ' THEN 
   UPDATE B SET Status = 'Ongoing' WHERE C_No = '3000';
COMMIT;
```

In the above MySQL `TRANSACTION` statement, I want to get the `@v` from the `table A` and if `@v EXISTS` (ie. if there is a value/row for `Case_No = '2000'`) then I want to update a row in `table B` from `'Status'` to `'Ongoing'`

The above syntax didnt work.

What is the correct MySQL syntax to do the above `TRANSACTION` work?

The table structures are as follows:

> Structure of table A : A(Case_No,Clientno)
>
> Structure of table B : B(C_No,Status)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that clear.

Guessing tableB.C_no is reference of tableA.ClientNo

```
update
    tableB
set Status = 'Ongoing'
where C_No = ( select Clientno from tableA where Case_No = 2000 )
```

If it's not reference table then try

```
update
    tableB
set Status = 'Ongoing'
where C_No = 3000
and ( select count(Clientno) from tableA where Case_No = 2000) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Your question is not clear enough. I am answering this question based on my understanding of question

You can also use update with inner join. For Example:

`update b inner join a on A.Case_No = B.C_No set status='on_going' where A.Case_No = 2000 and B.C_No = 3000;`

This query will select only those rows from `A` which has an entry in `B`. So you don't have to worry about if A has that row or not.